# SQL: extract multiple rows from one record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have got a table "Photo_users" like this:

> ID Name Surname Title1 Title2

where Title1 and Title 2 are the titles of two photos uploaded by the user "Name Surname". I would like to export a list of photo titles with respective author (every author has max 2 photos of course):

```
Name Surname Title1
Name Surname Title2
...
...
...
```

I know the structure of the DB is not the best one for what I want to do, but this is what I have.

Any hint? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select name, surname, title1 from photo_users
union all
select name, surname, title2 from photo_users
```

If needed, add additional `NULL` checks or change `UNION ALL` into `UNION` to avoid duplicates

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name, surname, title1 AS title
FROM photo_users
UNION
SELECT name, surname, title2 AS title
FROM photo_users
```

And if you want it sorted/filtered....

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT name, surname, title1 AS title
    FROM photo_users
    WHERE id>100
    UNION
    SELECT name, surname, title2 AS title
    FROM photo_users
    WHERE id>100
) AS ilv
ORDER BY surname, name;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  u.Name,
  u.Surname,
  CASE x.t
    WHEN 1 THEN u.Title1
    WHEN 2 THEN u.Title2
  END AS Title
FROM Photo_users u
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS t UNION ALL SELECT 2) x
```

Answer (score 1):

```
( SELECT name
       , surname
       , title1 AS title
  FROM photo_users
  WHERE title1 IS NOT NULL
)
UNION ALL
( SELECT name
       , surname
       , title2 AS title
  FROM photo_users
  WHERE title2 IS NOT NULL
)
```

---

But first, consider **normalizing** your table.

It's really as simple as

- adding another table `photo` with fields `title` and `userid` (foreign key to table `photo_users`) and other related and not normalized fields (like `photo`) you probably have.
- transfering data (titles and other related fields) from the table you have to the new one
- dropping the field `title` from table `photo_users`

You will then be able to

- write this query (and all others queries which use the photos/titles) with a simple `JOIN`
- and not with complex and possibly slow `UNION` queries
- have stored more than two photos for a user
- have stored less than two photos for some users without having any `NULL` in the related fields.